# Angular 2 Observable Interval locks out UI

Tags: angular, rxjs

When I use a `Observable.Interval` to perform a http refresh of a UI it locks out the buttons on the UI from working if the interval is too fast. The buttons do not register the click, seems to be a timing issue. If I increase the timing and therefore miss the get call the buttons work, but the data is then delayed in updating.

**Interval**

```
this.dataSub = Observable.interval(1000).subscribe(x => {
  this.getData();
})
```

**getData**

```
 getData(): void {
     this.dataService.getData()
         .subscribe(
              data => this.data = data,
              error => console.log("Error HTTP Get Service" + this.data),
              () => {});
 }
```

Is there a best practice, or something I'm missing that I should be doing to refresh the UI but not lock out the buttons

Comment: Is the button click calling getData method directly?

Comment: No, the button is not related to the getData method, there are dozens of buttons and they all stop responding. If the interval is 1000 then it happens maybe 1 in 10 clicks, as you decrease the interval it happens more frequently.

Comment: Can you show what's inside getData function?

Comment: Updated the original post with the getData function

Comment: Without having access to more code, it is hard to say for sure, but one thing is clear - too much JS runs whenever the interval fires. This is likely because the change detector is running every time and has a lot of work to do (are you using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` where possible?). Can you record a JS profile in Chrome DevTools and post an image of the flame chart?

Comment: I believe that your function is executed again before first execution finish. Probably you should add some condition is getData is already finished and then allow it to be called again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## The theory

In general, you should avoid explicitly subscribing to observables wherever possible. Instead, use all of the operators (yes, it can be very tricky to figure out the right ones) available to compose all the source/input observables into one or more observables that you use in the view with the `async` pipe.

> Don't forget that JS is single threaded (aside from workers). Your UI and most Angular code has to share the one thread, so long running JS locks up your UI.

This has three main benefits:

1. It's almost impossible to cause memory leaks. If you don't remember to always unsubscribe in the `ngOnDestroy()` hook or when you no longer care about it, you risk creating a memory leak whenever you manually subscribe. Whereas the `async` pipe will unsubscribe correctly when the component/element it is used on gets destroyed - you don't need to worry about it.
2. Doing less work. Using operators like `switchMap()`, `switchLatest()`, etc, you can cancel and cleanup superceded HTTP calls and other expensive operations, or even stop them before they have started if they are no longer required. Don't do more than you have to. This also usually means the change detection doesn't have to run as much, which means better performance.
3. Cleaner code. Less member variables, more functional-like code. Yes, it can be a little harder to understand when you are learning Rx, but it gets easier.

## In practice

With all that in mind, how could you apply it to your code?

One thing you may not be aware of (many people aren't) is that if your `DataService.getData()` method is something like:

```
getData(): Observable<MyData[]> {
    return this.http.get('http://some.url/data').map(res => res.json());
}
```

then every time you subscribe to the observable created by the `Http` service, a new request is made. This is what you want, but what you *don't* want is to process the results from any previous requests as soon as a new one is made.

So you could instead just compose one observable with the latest data from the most recent request using something like this in your controller:

```
 ngOnInit() {
     // (I follow a convention where observable properties end in $)
     this.data$ = Observable.interval(1000).flatMapLatest(() => {
         return this.dataService.getData();
     });
 }
```

No subscriptions, just a created observable. Then in your view, just use the async pipe with the `data$` property and you are golden.

For example:

```
<ul *ngFor="let d of (data$ | async); trackBy: d?.id">
    <li>{{d.name}}</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: fyi the "stream$" notation is called ["finnish notation"](https://medium.com/@benlesh/observables-and-finnish-notation-df8356ed1c9b#.9br3ma2h4).

Comment: @paulpdaniels TIL. Thanks! (I also spotted a goof in the example markup I posted thanks to you)

Comment: After using subscribe to get data from an observable, I tried this and liked how it worked.  But does anyone know if you can add an async pipe to something like: {{data ? data.length : 0}} or can you use async at all when you need to check a property on a returned set (like length)?

Comment: Additional note: I did try {{date ? data.length : 0 | async }}. It didn't complain, but I'm also not sure if it worked.

Comment: @MikeWitt I am assuming that `data` is an observable property on your controller. In that case, I would write your expression like so: `{{ (data | async)?.length || 0 }}`. [Plunkr demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/W4BNYhbsCuHq5Uiad1Ml?p=preview).