# UI blocking when observable/subscribe refreshes

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have an observable with an interval timer to refresh the data every couple of seconds. This looks like:

```
return Observable.interval(2000)
  .switchMap(() => this.http.get(this.url)
  .map(this.extractData))
```

where the "extractData" method massages the data some. On the other end I have 2 subscribers. One uses the data as is and puts it into an array for display like:

```
this.myService.getData()
  .subscribe(
    data => this.data = data,
    error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  )
```

I have have another subscriber that further summarizes the data for its display and it looks like:

```
this.myService.getData()
  .subscribe(
  data=> this.summarizeData(data),
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
  )
```

All this work perfectly, but after I get a sizeable number of records (the list grows over time), like around 1000, I notice that the UI freezes for a noticeable period of time. Yes I know I can work at keeping the list size to a smaller number, but for now I'd like to see if I can solve it with this larger data set.

So I looked at other posts and found an interesting approach on the [answer to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41557987/angular-2-observable-interval-locks-out-ui/41558532) and gave it a try by sending an observable to the display and using the async pipe. I pretty much got the same result where every couple of seconds the UI froze for a short period.

Any suggestions on which approach is preferred? All the examples put a subscribe in the component like I'm doing. Then, any suggestions on ways to keep the UI from freezing?

UPDATE: Per @Nicolas I've looked into using Angular Zones to get the http get to run outside of Angular's zone (which seem to be the bottle neck as each subscription seems to be causing it to take about 200-400 ms depending on the number of records). So maybe I'm not quite understanding how to make this work in a helpful way (I can make it work, but it doesn't seem to helping, which makes me think I'm doing something wrong).

If I understand correctly, I would use the "runOutsideAngular" method to run some code outside Angular's zone. Then use "run" to assign things back into the Angular zone so that change detection can work and update the display.

So I tried to do something on both the Observable end and the Subscriber end. But, like I said, neither seemed to help. Any pointers in the right direction would help!

Observable end:

```
return Observable.interval(2000)
.switchMap(() => this.doGet());

private doGet(): ObservableInput<any> {
  return this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
  return  this.http.get(this.url).map(this.extractData).catch(this.handleError);
  });
}
```

Subscriber side:

```
this.zone.runOutsideAngular(() => {
this.myService.getData()
.subscribe(
  data => {
    this.zone.run(() => this.data = data)
  },
  error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look into zone.js and run your calculations outside of angular zone and only update the view when you want to update. It will boost your performance quite significantly.
Take a look at this article this will gives you a good start.
[Angular zone](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2017/02/21/using-zones-in-angular-for-better-performance.html)

Apart from that you should change the change detection strategy to `OnPush` and carefully updates your model accordingly.

Comment: I've updated my original post with what I've tried. Thanks for your suggestions (and interesting articles!), but it hasn't helped to solve the problem.  Please take a look at my update. Mike

Comment: It looks like you are making lots of request using multiple `this.myService.getData()` Its a cold observable so every time you call it you are not subscribing to the same stream but a new one. Try using a Subject that allow multiple observers.